# How can I reference a list element in `BottomNavigationBarItem` title attribute?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of `Widget` defined as:

```dart
static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: Account',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: _widgetOptions.elementAt(0), // this is an error
          )
```

In above code, I see an compile error when I assign the first element in the list to `title` attribute of BottomNavigationBarItem: `The values in a const list literal must be constants`.

It seems that the `title` value needs to be a `const` but the value in the widget list is not a const. How can I convert it to a const value?

Below is the code where BottomNaviationBarItem is used:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: _widgetOptions.elementAt(0),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            title: Text('Business'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_box),
            title: Text('Account'),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you post full code of where are you using BottomNavigationBarItem

Comment: I have added the code in the post

Comment: It's impossable. List.elementAt() return E not const E.And const List only restrict  _widgetOptions cannot point to other, it cannot define its' element is const.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao just remove 'const' in your build method in "... items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>..." and it will work

Comment: @ASLOUN you are right, it works.